# io.jenkins.plugins.appcenter.AppCenterException: No file found matching pattern

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to upload `.ipa` file to AppCenter using Jeinkins, but getting the following exception:

```
+ pwd
/Users/maniprasannakumar/.jenkins/workspace/IOS_Test
+ xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath /Users/maniprasannakumar/.jenkins/workspace/IOS_Test/builds/RemoteLync.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist /Users/maniprasannakumar/Desktop/jenkinsarchinve/kiddeExportOptions.plist -exportPath /Users/maniprasannakumar/Desktop/jenkinsarchinve/
2022-01-03 12:09:16.138 xcodebuild[35412:1166670] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/hy/f06dhv196hx6bywh9lhm2ptr0000gn/T/RemoteLync_2022-01-03_12-09-16.136.xcdistributionlogs'.
Exported RemoteLync to: /Users/maniprasannakumar/Desktop/jenkinsarchinve
** EXPORT SUCCEEDED **

ERROR: Build step failed with exception
io.jenkins.plugins.appcenter.AppCenterException: No file found matching pattern: '/Users/maniprasannakumar/Desktop/jenkinsarchinve/RemoteLync.ipa'
```

Comment: Can you run the following listing command before you attempt to upload ipa to appcenter: ls /Users/maniprasannakumar/Desktop/jenkinsarchinve/

Comment: + ls /Users/maniprasannakumar/Desktop/jenkinsarchinve/
DistributionSummary.plist
ExportOptions.plist
Packaging.log
RemoteLync.ipa
kiddeExportOptions.plist
ERROR: Build step failed with exception

Comment: i tried ls command there files 
+ ls /Users/maniprasannakumar/Desktop/jenkinsarchinve/
DistributionSummary.plist
ExportOptions.plist
Packaging.log
RemoteLync.ipa
kiddeExportOptions.plist
ERROR: Build step failed with exception

Comment: io.jenkins.plugins.appcenter.AppCenterException: No file found matching pattern: '/Users/maniprasannakumar/Desktop/jenkinsarchinve/RemoteLync.ipa' thinking what is pattren

Comment: Can you share where and how you defined the path to the ipa for the appcenter plugin

Comment: It seems like the plugin is expecting *relative path*, so you will have to export the .ipa file to the workspace of the job and provide the relative path to the file.